# Python __str__ no returning the desired result

Tags: python, flask

I'm working on my first few weeks of pythong, and i'm trying to modify some code from a course im following.

I have added some data into a mssql, and I want to extract that table into my flask page.

I was told to use **str** for my class, and I have added that, but i'm still not getting a proper result.

My app.py code is here:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, redirect
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine



app = Flask(__name__)

app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "mssql://@UB-tucIMS9NpXKF\\SQLEXPRESS/LOCAL_UBBI?driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server"
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
Migrate(app,db)
db.init_app(app)


class Products(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'Products'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    Name = db.Column(db.Text)
    Code = db.Column(db.Integer)
    


def __init__(self,id, name, code):
        self.id = id 
        self.name = name
        self.code = code

def __str__(self):
    return f"Product: ('number {self.id} is: {self.name}, {self.code}')"

  
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('home.html')

  
@app.route('/products')
def listProducts():
    myProducts = Products.query.all()
    
    return render_template('listProducts.html', myProducts=myProducts)
    
  


if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(debug=True)
```

And my view file's code is:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div class="jumbotron">

    <p>list products</p>
    {{ myProducts }}
    <!--{{ myProducts.name }}-->
    <!--<ul>


        {% for eachproduct in myProducts  %}
        <li>{{eachproduct}}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>-->

</div>
{% endblock %}
```

But my output if not my string representation of my object:
[image]

What am I missing ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you return the instance name not the string version of the instance (print does but not all api/framework). try to call `eachproduct.__str__()`

Comment: I tried adding:
 <li>{{eachproduct.__str__()}}</li>
        {% endfor %}

But still not correct:
list products

<Products 1>
<Products 2>
<Products 3>
<Products 4>
<Products 5>

Comment: The code shown here is not indented properly. `__str__` is defined as a global function, not a method of the `Products` class.

Answer (score 0):

Use `repr` instead of `str` to declare or print the official string representation of an object. In your case you can represent it with something like this.

```py
def __repr__(self):
        return f'<id: {self.id}, name: {self.name}, code: {self.code}>'
```